# How can I match a partial string to a database's object's attribute? Regexp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, database, postgresql

I have a database containing a list of movies. A typical entry look like this:

```
id: 1, 
title: "Manhatten and the Murderer", 
year: 1928, 
synopsis: 'some text...' 
rating: 67, 
genre_id, etc. etc.
```

Now I'm trying to make a series of search tests pass and so far I have made a single test case pass where if you type the title "Manhatten and the Murderer" in a text field it will find the movie that you want. The problem is with partial matching.

Now I'd like a way to search "Manhat" and match the record "Manhatten and the Murderer". I also want it to match with any movie that has "Manhat" in it. For example, it would return maybe 2 or 3 others like title: "My life in Manhattan", title: "The Big Apple in Manhattan" etc. etc.

Below is the code that I have so far in my Movie model:

```
def self.search(query)
# Replace this with the appropriate ActiveRecord calls...

if query =~ where(title:)
  #where(title: query)
  binding.pry
end


end
```

My question is, how can I set this up? My problem is the "where(title:) line. One thought was to use Regexp to match the title attribute. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use a query that searches a substring in between:

```
name = "Manhattan"
Movie.where("title like ?", "%#{name}%")
```

For example:

- `%Manhattan` will get you: `Love in Manhattan`
- `Manhattan%` will get:     `Manhattan and Company`
- `%Manhattan%` will get you both: `[Love in Manhattan, Manhattan and Company]`

But, if you're searching through movies synopsis, you should use [Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/quickstart.html) or [Elastic Search](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1)

For example, with Elastic Search, you could set the synopsis like this:

Add `app/indices/movie_index.rb`:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :movie, :with => :active_record do
  # fields
  indexes title, :sortable => true
  indexes synopsis
end
```

Index your data with `rake ts:index`

And then run Sphynx with: `rake ts:start`

You can search just like this:

`Movie.search :conditions => {:synopsis => "Manhattan"}`

---

Elastic Search is a great alternative to ThinkingSphinx, there's even a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1) about it, so you should definitely take a look to see what really suites you best... Hope this helps!

Comment: and if you want case insensitive, in PostgreSQL you can use `ilike`. Or use the `~*` operator and a regexp.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need regex to find movies that have the search string. You can use SQL query like this:

```
Movie.where('title LIKE ?','Batman%')
```

That would return all movies start with "Batman"

```
Movie.where('title LIKE ?','%Batman%')
```

That would return all movies that have Batman anywhere in it's title.
I think you figured out the '%' is a joker character in the query.

Comment: I see what you did there.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run a search server alongside your Rails application. It is certainly my go to solution. This route offers a ton of features not found within Rails itself and might be overkill, but worth consideration.

I use Sphinx and implement it using the thinking-sphinx gem.

Resources:

http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/

http://sphinxsearch.com/